# How to insulate the inside of a door

Tags: insulation, doors, sound-proofing

I am building a sliding door with a frame made of 2x2s covered with plywood panels on each side. I would like to make it reasonably soundproof and was planning on filling the void with some insulation material.

What would be a good material to use in between the panels of plywood?

Here's a peek at what the door will look like: https://s3-production.bobvila.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DIYSlidingDoor_Step07.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider some of that "solid" expanded foam insulation with or without aluminum facing...

Should be available in a 2" thickness, cut to fit and possibly glued should work well.